# I want to read textbox control from pdf file using C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have 1 pdf file and it contains registration form, in that it contains Text textbox controls, so I want to read those textbox Id of pdf file and write some static value in it and create new pdf file , is it possible??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. However, you need to use third party component.

We use [ActivePDF Portal](http://examples.activepdf.com/Portal/2014/Populate_fields_prior_to_load.cs) which is a commercial version. However, you can download [trial version](http://www.activepdf.com/myaccount/downloads).

Comment: here i enable to find the textbox ID to write some value, so can u tell me how can I find the textbox control Id

Comment: Could you create a new question and post your code?